# Laravel - query from database and save to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome! I try to find a solution for my problem but it's hard for fresh laravel user. I try to do some simple booking system. I have 2 tables: schedule, and bids. What I want to do is display schedule table and via "book" button save it to bids table. I know how to query schedule table but I don't know how to write controller to save same data to another table.

Regards and thank you for the help.

Comment: Are bids and button two tables or two databases? I think you mean two tables here. correct me if  I am wrong.

Comment: @mindaJalaj my fault 2 tables in one database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in in the same controller class by adding a new function inside it. Here is the sample code.

```
class YourController extends Controller
{

public function bookSchedule()
{
    //here we are getting the data from the table
    $s = Schedule::where('id','=',98)
                ->select('colomn_1','colomn_2')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
    // here we are storing it back to the bids table
    Bids::insert($s);
}
```

Hope the answer has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should show some examples of what have you done,

also your database connection file

however you should connect the 2 databases in `app/config/database.php` like the following

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and then in the controller you can chose which database you are talking to 
for example `$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);`

[check the Laravel Documents](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: my fault , i meant two tables in one database